# not able to set background image in .net 6

Tags: html, css

[folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dF0B.png)attached image is my project setup and folder directory and I have included poster.jpg as a background image in StyleSheet.css like this :

**

```
*`body {
    background-image: url('\poster.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}`*
```

**
and then I am including this StyleSheet in _Layout.cshtml like this :

```
<link href="../styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="StyleSheet" />
```

.When I run the app background image is not getting rendered and I'm getting console error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".
can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: Backslashes aren't used in `url()` values in CSS. You'll likely want `url('/poster.jpg');` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be `background-image: url('/poster.jpg')` with "/" not "\"